# Iterate RDD and Stored value in Array Or Any other Collection in scala spark

Tags: arrays, scala, hadoop, apache-spark, rdd

I am new to scala. I am iterating RDD and storing each value in array or any other collection. But value is not storing inside Array.

```
val ItrRdd = sqlContext.sql("select district,state FROM world ").rdd
var ItrRdd_data = ItrRdd.map { x =>
       (x.getString(0), x.getString(1))
    }

var district = Array[String]()

ItrRdd_data.map{ x => 
      district.+:(x._1)
    }
```

Then If I print **district** then it will be blank.
Can someone help me to do this or other similar to above one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. `+:` doesn't change `district`, it creates a new array; 2. read http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#understanding-closures-a-nameclosureslinka.

Comment: whatever it may be....but i want that array should fill with values.

Comment: When problem 1 is fixed,  it still won'twork because this is Spark - the OP can't use a variable `district` and expect it will be distributed across the works. OP: you need to produce an RDD for `district` (then `collect()` afterwards) or (usually not so good a solutoin) use an accumulator.

Comment: @DarshanManek, then follow point 2. You need to understand how Spark works to make this happen

Comment: Thanks But Can you please tell me how can i do it with Accumulator.

Comment: @DarshanManek No, I won't. You're going to have to learn the basics of Spark at some point, you can't develop an app just by repeated questions on [SO]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the below to get compute the `district`

```
val district = ItrRdd_data.map({ case(x,y) => x -> y }).collect()
```

Comment: Hi @rogue-one This also will work but I want Both column will stored records in same order. Then if I Use above way then Chances that order of data inside both array will be different as it was not in master table.

Comment: @DarshanManek I have updated the answer to have both the columns.. and if you are concerned about the order of the columns changing.. they wont change.. or is that you want the order of rows to remain the same?

Comment: Then if I have more than two field. Then how can i do it in case and x -> y  ?

Comment: case(x1,x2,x3,x4,...) => (x1,x2,x3,x4...) and so on